# $(1+i\tan(\beta))^n$ in an expoential form

Tags: complex-numbers

I would like to find $\alpha$ and $r$ such that : 
$$(1+i\tan(\beta))^n = r \cdot e^{i \alpha}$$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

So far I've found that : $r = |\frac{1}{\cos \beta}|^n$ but I don't know how to proceed for the rest of the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:
\begin{align*}
(1+i\tan(\beta))^n
&=\left(1+i\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\cos(\beta)}\right)^n\\
&=\frac{(\cos(\beta)+i\sin(\beta))^n}{\cos^n(\beta)}\\
&=\frac{(\exp(i\beta))^n}{\cos^n(\beta)}\\
&=\frac 1{\cos^n(\beta)}e^{in\beta}
\end{align*}
thus $r=\frac 1{\cos^n(\beta)}$ (it's no required $r\geq 0$ but only $r\in\mathbb R$) and $\alpha=n\beta$.